# How do I achieve a Soft Translucent Navigation Bar in Lollipop?

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation, android-5.0-lollipop

How do I achieve a Soft Translucent Navigation Bar for my app in Lollipop like the attached?

Thank you

[image: Soft Translucent Navigation Bar]

Comment: You have to show us some sort of effort in solving the problem. StackOverflow isn't a 'code-order' website. [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? What possible solutions do you think there are? Have you tried looking around for this answer anywhere else?

Comment: I have tried adding the following to my theme:
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item> however, it only makes the navigation semi-transparent and does not add the soft gradient appearance. I have looked everywhere online and cant seem to find a solution. Thank you for taking the time to read my question :)

Comment: Possible solutions i would think is a certain command in theme, or trying to make the navigation fully transparent then adding a linear gradient to the bottom to give the attached appearance - however i haven't found a way to change navigation bar's opacity to 0.